# Is it possible to use hostel booking for a UK Standard Visitor visa application or must it be a hotel?

Tags: visas, uk, bookings, paperwork, accommodation

I'm going to stay there for about a month.

Answer (score 3):

[Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) as to what NOT to submit includes:

> This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to 
>   consider your application.

if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies 
of the same documents

- bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of
  application
- driving licence
- photographs (other than passport photographs required in section 1)
- notarial certificates
- business cards
- **hotel bookings**
- ...

Comment: In my case it is necessary to provide a proof of booking

Comment: Thanks alot Should I mention anything in the additional information section of the visa application?

Comment: I'm applying for standard visitor visa to set for my plab exam ,all other applicants informed me that I have to provide a proof of accommodation  booking

Comment: @Esma.med other applicants told you wrong. You need the PLAB registration but not a hotel booking.

Comment: @GayotFow for a worried applicant, would it make sense to include a statement listing documents that are available but have not been included in the application because of the advice in the guidance? Or would mere mention of such documents raise red flags?

Comment: @phoog it's best to show you read the guidance. But a worried applicant can always say in the remarks "My enclosures are informed by your guidance which indicates that bookings should not be included. I can procure and send these to you if requested to do so (as stated in your guidance)" etc etc etc...

Comment: I think the source was more complete.